"java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerInstanceProvider$Function has not been registered"
Getting the exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerInstanceProvider$Function has not been registered
In Spring Cloud Config Server.
Configured one spring cloud config server instance and few other spring boot apps to fetch config from the config server.
Config Server throws above mentioned exception and Spring Boot apps trying to access config from config server fail to start as spring.cloud.config.fail-fast property is set to true.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
